# In need of node displacement on z axis only

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, displacement, axis

I am working on a water shader, using nodes to displace the waves of an ocean. Here is the simplified version using a checker texture to visualize my problem.

Since I want to make a cross section of the ocean ( waves on top, and a smooth glass shader on the sides to see the inside ) I need the top of the plane of the cube to displace on the z axis only, while the sides adjust their height accordingly to touch the top plane. Is it possible, and how if it is, to stop X and Y from going outwards?

My Blender version is 2.83

[image: node setup used]

[image: subdivisions used]

[image: solid view]

[image: render isometric view]

[image: render side view]

[image: render top view]

[image: render water shader]

Comment: even with a Separate XYZ it seems to mess up on the X and Y axis. And I suppose you don't want to use the Displace modifier (you can constraint on the Z axis)

Comment: @moonboots I considered using the displacement modifier, but since I cant fully reproduce the waves I will use it as my last option. I just wondered if there would be another way besides using modifiers and baking out the displacement texture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Displacement" node displaces geometry along the local normal. If you want to push the geometry along a definite axis, you can use the "Vector Displacement" node and only populate the Z input field.

Don't forget to set the matrix to "World space" in the node though.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick answer! It works seamlessly with my custom water setup.